# How do I indicate that skills on my resume are similar to skills required for a job?

Tags: resume

I extensively used Silverlight to create applications in my past experience.

Now I am applying for a WPF position.

WPF and Silverlight are very similar and use pretty much the same technologies (e.g. XAML and MVVM). I am sure that I can do WPF projects with my Silverlight knowledge. But the recruiter doesn't know this. They just want to see the word WPF in my resume.

How can I show this similarity on my resume?

Comment: Here's a link for you. This was asked around a week ago: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98529/submitting-a-resume-easily-parsed-by-applicant-tracking-systems-atss-or-submit/98530#98530

Comment: Writing that you know WPF withour actually knowing it (even though you know a *similar* tech) is falsifying your CV

Comment: @GrayCygnus could you self-study WPF and then take some sort of exam in which a passing score would be justification for claiming that you "know" WPF?

Comment: @RobertColumbia usually recruiters are the ones that determine if you "know" or not, via some sort of test or interviews. Some certification or past projects on the subject is other way to "show" that you know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I show this similarity on my resume?

If you say both tools (WPF and Silverlight) use basically the same technology, you could try *listing the underlying technology in your resume instead* of the derivate product (WPF or SL).

To give an example, lets say both WPF and Silverlight use techologies `Foo`, `CoolXML`, and `Bar`. Then instead of saying you are expert in Silverlight you could say:

> Experience with Foo, CoolXML, and Bar (Used in tools like WPF or Silverlight)

This way you will not be lying or falsifying your resume by saying you know WPF (which you say you don't know currently) but still the recruiters will see the word they want in your CV.

Just be sure that if you are ever asked answer truthfully and don't say you know WPF. This could come back at you in a negative way. In the meantime, if those tools are indeed quite similar I suggest you start learning about WPF. Surely you will get it faster as you already know the underlying tech they use.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to lie but also I don't want to underestimate my skills. I know WPF and I worked on it before but they require 4 years experience. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Love hope this helps you out

Answer (score 1):

If you basically know it already, and being able to put it on your resume matters to you, then sit down in off-time and work with it a bit - maybe knock out a minor project.  It shouldn't take more than a couple of hours.  At that point, you can add it to your list of known technologies in all honesty, and if the question comes up on an interview, you can explain in more detail.  Showing a bit of initiative to learn new technologies will probably look good, too.

If you don't basically know it already, then trying this will help you figure that out before you go around making claims that you can't back up.

If being able to put it on your resume doesn't really matter to you, then just be honest with the skills that you have.