# How to Create a Parser-Friendly Resume / CV in PDF or Plain Text?

Tags: resume

I use LaTex to write my Resume and CV. For many job application sites, even though they "accept" PDF files, they will parse them and then fill in a form automatically, to be "helpful." However, these parsing systems perform very badly. I almost have to delete everything that is parsed and manually enter everything.

My main question is:
How, in terms of formatting, should you write a possibly plain-text Resume / CV, so that the automated resume parsers work perfectly for it? (That is, they fill in the forms accurately after you upload your resume.)

I have a secondary question, that would be nice if you can briefly discuss. Because the job application sites treat PDF resumes as plain text for parsing, is there a point to upload PDF resumes? Would a human be reading PDF resumes or reading the parsed result of the PDF?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submitting a resume easily parsed by applicant tracking systems (ATSs) or submiting a nicer one with which an ATS might have a bit of trouble parsing?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98529/submitting-a-resume-easily-parsed-by-applicant-tracking-systems-atss-or-submit)

Comment: Even though the question is similar, the answers there are not helpful actually. I hope there could be different insights.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think you'll get better traction on, and it's more appropriate for, the Tex - LaTex sub

Comment: @Gamora I don't have an issue with that.

Comment: I think it may be too old for us to migrate so hopefully we can close and you can post it over there

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use either. I've almost always used MS Word or at least supplied my CV in Word Document format.

The reason for this is that every agency I've ever dealt with can parse Word documents. They're human readable, and the agency will invariably chop off the contact details and/or add their own company branding to the top.

(Yes, it does mean that the agency can change it. But they could do that anyway).

I also include a copyright message on the last page in a very small font and more importantly a Last Updated field, top right of the first page. This is so when someone calls me and says "I have a copy of your CV...." I can find out how recent it is. I've had calls from people with a 4/5 year old copy who haven't realised, as the latest role always says dd/mm/yyyy - present.